# Converting two intergers in 1 excel cell to a date/time

Tags: excel, vba

In excel I have a date and time given to me as '011215 0800' this is 1/12/15 8:00 or January 12th 2015 at 8:00 AM, how can I convert this with a VBA macro.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a VBA macro? Anyway, you just split it into bits and feed it to the `datevalue` and `timevalue` functions. I don't see what your problem is, are you stuck somewhere with this or...?

Comment: a quick dirty formula: `=--REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,10,0,":"),5,0,"/"),3,0,"/")` then format it any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells you wish to process and run this:

```
Sub DateFixer()
    Dim yr As Long, mn As Long, dy As Long, hr As Long, mni As Long
    Dim r As Range, i As String
    For Each r In Selection
        i = r.Text
        r.Clear
        dy = CLng(Left(i, 2))
        mn = CLng(Mid(i, 3, 2))
        yr = CLng(Mid(i, 5, 2)) + 2000
        hr = CLng(Mid(i, 8, 2))
        mni = CLng(Right(i, 2))
        r.Value = DateSerial(yr, mn, dy) + TimeSerial(hr, mni, 0)
        r.NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy hh:mm"
    Next r
End Sub
```